# Robot Framework lint-rule: Too few keyword steps

Tags: robotframework

I have a test-suite containing one test-case which in turn only contain one test-step (keyword). When I try to commit it to our repo, there is a lint-rule preventing that.

**Question**: What would be the motivation for keeping this rule? Is the intention that things should be done in a different manner than I have done in my test-suite (robot-file) shown below?

---

In my Jenkins-log when trying to commit, I see following:
10:53:31 [INFO]: E: 10, 0: Too few steps (1) in test case (TooFewTestSteps)

In file "rf_lint.args" in our "commit_gate"-folder in our repo, I commented following rule:

#-e TooFewTestSteps

Then my commit went through the rf-lint.

This is how my .robot-file look that was not allowed:

```
*** Settings ***
  
Documentation       My Documentation  
Library             libraries/my_library.py  
Suite Setup         suite precondition  
Suite Teardown      suite postcondition  
Force Tags          my_tag  

*** Test Cases ***  
My Test Case  
    [Documentation]     My Test Case Documentation  
    my keyword  
    
*** Keywords ***
```

Comment: I feel that test cases should have action and verification that action had a correct result. Ideally, you should see this when you look at the test case. If you write keywords that do several things, you end up with maintenance problems. For example test case with two keywords, "enter wrong credentials" and "verify login failed" is better than "enter wrong credentials and verify login failed".

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the motivation for keeping this rule?

The motivation is to discourage creating a test with just one or two steps. For some teams this is considered a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

A test that calls only one keyword might be hard to understand since it might hide what the test is actually verifying. Unless the name of the keyword is self-documenting, you would have to dig into the implementation of the keyword to understand what the test is trying to accomplish.

If you and your team don't consider this to be a problem, there's nothing wrong with removing the rule.